# how to read active profile from different location in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I have my application.properties file in src/main/resources and i have my different active profile (application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties) in differenent directory as src/main/resources/properties.

**I'm using springboot version 2.7.5**

I tried to configure it in application.properties file which is in directory-src/main/resources
spring.profiles.active=dev

but it is not reading the application-dev.properties from directory src/main/resources/properties

For fixing this issue i created two class

```
@Configuration
public class ActiveProfileConfiguration extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationJPAConfiguration.class);
    private static final String SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE";
    String profile;
        protected void setSpringProfile(ServletContext servletContext) {
    if(null!= System.getenv(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE)){
        profile=System.getenv(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE);
    }else if(null!= System.getProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE)){
        profile=System.getProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE);
    }else{
        profile="local";
    }
    log.info("***** Profile configured  is  ****** "+ profile);

    servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", profile);
    }
    
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
public class DevPropertyReader {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource("application.properties"), new ClassPathResource("EnvironmentProfiles/application-local.properties") };
    ppc.setLocations(resources);
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    System.out.println("env active profile");
    return ppc;
    }
    
}
```

But still not able to resolve this issue.

Comment: The answers below focus on _moving_ your profile-specific files to the right location, but can you explain _why_ you have them in a sub-folder in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Spring will not look for property files files in your custom `/properties` folder :

> 21.2 Application property files SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations and add
> them to the Spring Environment:
>
> - A /config subdir of the current directory.
> - The current directory
> - A config package
> - The classpath root

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

The simplest solution would be to move it at the root of `src/main/resources` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Place .properties in structure like below:

```
src/
├─ main/
│  ├─ resources/
│  │  ├─ application.properties
│  │  ├─ application-dev.properties
│  │  ├─ application-prod.properties
```

Below Dockerfile example sets the right Spring Profile when running your application:

```
ENTRYPOINT java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar /app.jar
```

But there are many other options through WebApplicationInitializer, Beans XML, Maven profile, etc...